# Is the term "inflection angle" (for the angle of the tangent at an inflection point) used in English?

Tags: calculus, terminology

I read in a math book, written in Arabic, about some thing called "inflection angle", which is defined to be the angle of the tangent at the inflection point.

I couldn't find this term in English books. Do I miss the translation?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point)

Comment: I have never heard that term.